# Holomorphic branch of $\log z$ on $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

I got this problem while reading a book. Suppose $D$ is a simply connected subdomain such that $\mathbb{C}_\infty-D$ contains at least two points. Let $w_0,w_1\in \partial D$. Applying a conformal map wlog we can assume $w_0=0$ and $w_1=\infty$.Then $D$ is a simply connected subdomain of $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$,and so there exists a holomorphic branch of $\log z$ on $D$. Now my question is, does it follow that $D$ should be a subdomain in $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$? Also in the next line it take $N$ to be the unit disk and define $b=\Re(\frac{1}{\log z})$ on $D\cap N$. Then it says $b<0$ on $D\cap N$. How do we know it if $D$ contains the negative real axis?

Comment: No. I think the point is you can place the branch cut anywhere you like. For some situations, it might be more natural to place the branch cut along the negative imaginary axis by taking the argument to be in $(-\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ for example.

Comment: Here it is preferable not to think in term of branch cuts, but in term of an holomorphic function [on a spiral Riemann surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Complex_logarithm), and starting from any point of $\mathbb{C}$ (corresponding to a point of the spiral) you can draw a simply connected domain around it, and you'll get into troubles only when trying to make a closed loop around $z= 0$. Equivalently, it means that $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z} = 0$ whenever $\gamma$ doesn't make a closed loop around $0$, therefore $\log(z) = \int \frac{dz}{z}$ is well-defined on such a domain

Comment: Im still confused. I have edited my question with more details. Could you please look at it?

Comment: Firstly, the question isn't well defined since you *do* lose generality by taking $0\not\in D$, if your intent is to look for a branch of logarithm. Secondly (and more importantly), if $D$ is only defined up to a conformal mapping, then there isn't much sense is asking whether $(-\infty,0]\subseteq D$, since many conformal mappings exist who don't fix $(-\infty,0]$.